# How To Check If A User's iOS Device Supports Bluetooth Peer-To-Peer Connections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gamekit, game-center

What is the best way of programatically checking if the current device supports Bluetooth peer-to-peer GameKit connectivity? I am aware of how to check for Game Center support, but want to support devices on iOS 3 that have Bluetooth (I know all devices with bluetooth can be upgraded to iOS 4).

**Edit**: The app functions perfectly fine without Bluetooth, so I don't want `peer-peer` to be in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`.

Many thanks in advance,
jrtc27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know which device supports what, if you can detect device you can make it work. I found this method and it works for me. You can find [device capabilities here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW9).

//Return TRUE if Device Support X.

```
-(BOOL)platformSupported_X
{
NSString *platform = [self platform];
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return FALSE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return FALSE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return TRUE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return TRUE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return FALSE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return TRUE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return TRUE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return TRUE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return TRUE;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return TRUE;
return TRUE;
}
```

// Check Device Model

```
-(NSString *)platform
{
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
free(machine);
return platform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an elegant way to detect bluetooth peer-to-peer support based on the device type. You might want to consider basing the detection on the OS version instead (iOS 3.1 is the minimum for peer-to-peer):

```
NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
BOOL osSupportsBluetoothPeerToPeer = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);
```

In case the OS is 3.1 or later, but the device does not support bluetooth peer-to-peer, the system will inform the user about the lack of support. This seems to be what Apple prefers: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3621